# python handle different types

Tags: python, types, naming

I'm new to python, just have one question:

Python don't need to declare variable types. For example, when we use functions, we don't declare which type should be passed in. So sometimes, I can't figure out which type the passed in parameter actually is or do I pass in an invalid parameter.

For example, a parameter named: run_date, Its type can be string or datetime or date. I have to find it from the code...

Is there a way to solve this problem?
I think I should do good naming. But howto?

I don't mean to check the type in the code. I just get confused with the function parameters when coding... I always forget which type the parameter is...

Comment: I guess the most important part is to good naming of the variables, that indicate the type. For details use [Docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) - some Ide's/Editors display them and you can access this information in REPL
EDIT: I thought you asked how to determine the correct type to pass to another function, and not to check if the passed in parameter is of the correct type

Answer (score 2):

Python uses what is called "Duck Typing" i.e. if it looks like a duck and it sounds like a duck you might as well call it a duck.

You can use:

1. Parameter type checking,
2. Parameter conversion,
3. Exceptions &
4. **Documentation**

Answer (score 1):

Well ... welcome to the python world :).

You can define a function like this:

```
def value_type(x):
    # for type of dictionary
    if isinstance(x, dict):
        return list(set(x.values()))
    # for type of string including unicode 
    elif isinstance(x, str) or isinstance(x, unicode):
        mpla mpla...
    # for type of integer
    elif isinstance(x, int):
        mpla mpla...
    else:
        return None
```